# How to enable syntax highlighting when using nbsphinx with confluencebuilder?

Tags: confluence, nbsphinx

When I publish the docs of a project using confluencebuilder, the part of the documentation which was generated by nbsphinx (comprising a few tutorial notebooks) does not display synthax highlighting.

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187649/nbsphinx-syntax-highlighting-on-readthedocs) when publishing in ReadTheDocs (i.e. html), but there it was solved by installing IPython (and ensuring the correct lexer was available for the highlighting).

In the case of confluence, however, I am a bit lost.

Inspecting the output files I notice that codeblocks associated with Python notebook cells is set to none, e.g.

```
<div><ac:structured-macro ac:name="code">
<ac:parameter ac:name="language">none</ac:parameter>
<ac:parameter ac:name="linenumbers">false</ac:parameter>
<ac:parameter ac:name="title">\[33\]:</ac:parameter>
<ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[var = 42]]></ac:plain-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
</div>
```

Is there a way to at least force nbsphinx or confluencebuilder to fall back to python and highlight the code in notebook cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax highlighting can be fixed by adding the following to Sphinx's conf.py:

```
def translation_override(lang):
    if lang in ['ipython', 'ipython2', 'ipython3']:
        lang = 'python'

    return lang

confluence_lang_transform = translation_override
```

I found the answer and the above snippet in [this discussion](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/confluencebuilder/issues/764#issuecomment-1434093878) on github.

What is happening is that the language in the in the notebook's code blocks being processed is not being set to 'python' but to 'ipython' – which confluence does not understand. Fortunately, `confluencebuilder` comes with the [confluence_lang_transform](https://sphinxcontrib-confluencebuilder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration/#confval-confluence_lang_transform) configuration setting, which allows one to translate one language into another, fixing the issue.